# Unable/Error while getting preferredDataLocation in users/delta API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

With reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0.

**Expected or Desired Behavior**

With reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0. while making user/delta API call we should get preferredDataLocation for multi geo

**Observed Behavior**

Unable to get preferredDataLocation in users/delta API
URL used : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,mail,userType,userPrincipalName,accountEnabled,displayName,assignedPlans,preferredDataLocation

Image: Error In Postman Request

[image]

> Response headers corresponding to your request(s):
>
> Date - Wed, 03 Jul 2019 07:25:2 
>   request-id - 1d42128-c88b-4e1c-9fd8-c6e0f7519a37 SPRequestGuid -
>   1d8dec9e-c071-0000-3f4a-597faa9ba2ef
>
> **Steps to Reproduce**

Make graph API call with graph token
URL used : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,mail,userType,userPrincipalName,accountEnabled,displayName,assignedPlans,preferredDataLocation

Comment: Do you have any more concern?

Answer (score 1):

`preferredDataLocation` is not supported for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta`

You could use `Microsoft Graph API Beta Version` Use the below API URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,mail,userType,userPrincipalName,preferredDataLocation
```

See the screen shot :

[image]

**Point To Remember:**

1. If your `DataLocation` is not configured you have to configure it
   other then `preferredDataLocation` will be shown as `Null`
2. You can have a look here how could you [configure DataLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/multi-geo-tenant-configuration#add-the-multi-geo-capabilities-in-office-365-plan-to-your-tenant)